# My server not responding to grep

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to use this command on my server

```
grep -lr --include=*.php "eval(base64_decode" /path/to/webroot
```

Absolutely nothing happens, no response from the server.

Can anyone help me out?
I am not an experienced Linux user.

Comment: To understand your problem first eliminate the fancy arguments. Can you get `grep "eval(base64_decode" /path/to/webroot/subdir/one_phpFileOnly.php` to work? (just get the search to work for one file first). I bet it doesn't work, what about `grep "eval" /path/to...oneFileOnly.php` ? I bet that works. So it's probably the `(` char. How about `grep "eval[(]base..." ....`? Else `grep "eval[\(]base ..."` Once that is working, then you can go for the more general solution and add back the other args. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The GNU folks messed up when they gave grep arguments to recursively search for files. Forget you ever heard of `-r` or `--include` and rewrite your script to use `find` to **find** the files and `grep` to **G**lobally search for a **R**egular **E**xpression and **P**rint (`g/re/p`) the result from each file (see the huge clues in the tool names?). For example:

```
find /path/to/webroot -name '*.php' -print0 |
xargs -0 grep -l 'eval(base64_decode'
```

If that still gives you an issue then step 1 in debugging it is to run the `find` on it's own and see if it produces a list of files. If so, then step 2 is to run the `grep` alone on one of the files output by `find`. If you can't figure it out from that, let us know.